# Could the court compel a man to marry

Tags: halacha, marriage

I’ve heard that the court could compel a man to find a wife unless he was fully involved in the study of Torah.  Is this true?

Comment: See https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.1.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa) pointed out in his comment, above, this is the theoretical Halacha, but not enforced in practice, according to the Remo in Shulchan Aruch, Even HaEzer 1:3.

More so, the Rambam (Nedarim 8:13) points out that if a person were to make a Neder that he is going to get married, one cannot force him to do so unless one finds them an appropriate soulmate.

From here I understand that even in those times and places where people were "forced" to get married, it was only to appropriate soulmates, not to the first available person of the opposite gender.

Also, keep in mind that the Mitzva of Ve'Ahavta - "loving your neighbor" - is primarily towards one spouse (Kidushin 41a), thus forcing people to get married without them liking each other would mean forcing them to transgress this very important Torah concept (to paraphrase Rabbi Akiva).

Interestingly enough, the Rambam (Ishus 15:3) writes the other way around:

> מִי שֶׁחָשְׁקָה נַפְשׁוֹ בַּתּוֹרָה תָּמִיד וְשׁוֹגֶה בָּהּ כְּבֶן עֲזַאי וְדָבֵק בָּהּ כָּל יָמָיו וְלֹא נָשָׂא אִשָּׁה אֵין בְּיָדוֹ עָוֹן. וְהוּא שֶׁלֹּא יִהְיֶה יִצְרוֹ מִתְגַּבֵּר עָלָיו. אֲבָל אִם הָיָה יִצְרוֹ מִתְגַּבֵּר עָלָיו חַיָּב לִשָּׂא אִשָּׁה וַאֲפִלּוּ הָיוּ לוֹ בָּנִים שֶׁמָּא יָבוֹא לִידֵי הִרְהוּר:‏

One who is in love with Torah learning need not get married. However, if he cannot control his lustful thoughts he must get married.

Rambam (Nedarim 8:13) in the original:
יג:  מי שנשבע או נדר שישא אשה או שיקנה בית או שיצא בשיירא או יפרוש בים **אין מחייבין אותו לישא אשה או לקנות או לצאת מיד אלא עד שימצא דבר ההגון לו.** מעשה באשה שנדרה שכל מי שיתבע אותה תנשא לו וקפצו עליה בני אדם שאינן הגונין לה. ואמרו חכמים לא נתכוונה זו אלא לכל מי שיתבע אותה מן ההגונין לה וכן כל כיוצא בזה:‏

Shulchan Aruch, Even HaEzer 1:3.
מצוה על כל אדם שישא אשה בן י"ח והמקדים לישא בן י"ג מצוה מן המובחר אבל קודם י"ג לא ישא דהוי כזנות ובשום ענין לא יעבור מך' שנה בלא אשה **ומי שעברו עליו ך' שנה ואינו רוצה לישא ב"ד כופין אותו לישא כדי לקיים מצות פריה ורביה** ומיהו אם עוסק בתורה וטרח בה ומתיירא לישא אשה כדי שלא יטרח במזונו ויתבטל מן התורה מותר להתאחר:‏

 ***הגה*** **ובזמן הזה נהגו שלא לכוף ע"ז** וכן מי שלא קיים פריה ורביה ובא לישא אשה שאינה בת בנים כגון עקרה וזקנה או קטנה משום שחושק בה או משום ממון שלה אע"פ שמדינא היה למחות בו לא נהגו מכמה דורות לדקדק בענין הזיווגים ואפי' בנשא אשה ושהה עמה עשרה שנים לא נהגו לכוף אותו לגרשה אע"פ שלא קיים פריה ורביה וכן בשאר ענייני זיווגים: (ריב"ש סי' ט"ו) ובלבד שלא תהא אסורה עליו:‏

Kidushin 41a:
דאמר רב יהודה אמר רב אסור לאדם שיקדש את האשה עד שיראנה שמא יראה בה דבר מגונה ותתגנה עליו ורחמנא אמר {ויקרא יט-יח} ואהבת לרעך כמוך.‏

Comment: Thank you for the answer